# Cannot print content of PrimeFaces TexEditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, glassfish

I have a problem with PrimeFaces TextEditor.

I want to print [content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML97t.jpg) that is inside TextEditor, but when I click "Print" button I only get [blank PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBjiy.jpg). Is there maybe a mistake in code or I missed something?

**textEditor.xhtml:**

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <div class="card">
                <h:form>    
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0">Text editor</h3>
                    <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1" value="#{editorView.text}"  height="400" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>

                    <h:outputText id="text_to_print" escape="false" value="#{editorView.text}" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Preview" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-circle-zoomin" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Print" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print">
                        <p:printer target="text_to_print" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="button" onclick="PF('editor1').clear();" icon="ui-icon-close" />

                    <p:dialog header="Preview" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                        <p:outputPanel id="display">
                            <h:outputText value="#{editorView.text}" escape="false" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:dialog>     
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

**Managed bean (EditorView.java)**

```
package org.primefaces.ultima.view.input;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean

public class EditorView {

private String text;

private String text2;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getText2() {
    return text2;
}

public void setText2(String text2) {
    this.text2 = text2;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Jan it is very simple you do not update the text_to_print

```
 <h:form>    
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0">Text editor</h3>
                    <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1" value="#{editorView.text}"  height="400" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>

                    <h:outputText id="text_to_print" escape="false" value="#{editorView.text}" />
```

If this does not work please check your button id. Depends on your DOM tree it may be different

```
                    <p:commandButton value="Preview" update="display,text_to_print" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-circle-zoomin" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Print" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print">
                        <p:printer target="text_to_print" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="button" update="text_to_print" onclick="PF('editor1').clear();" icon="ui-icon-close" />

                    <p:dialog header="Preview" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                        <p:outputPanel id="display">
                            <h:outputText value="#{editorView.text}" escape="false" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:dialog>     
                </h:form>
```

your quesiton from the comment:

It can be done with the remoteCommand:

```
<p:commandButton  value="Go" 
     update="display,text_to_print"
    onsuccess="doAfter()"/>

<p:remoteCommand name="doAfter" oncomplete="document.getElementById('printForm:print').click()"   >

                  </p:remoteCommand>
```

remember to change your form and your button. you have to give them an Id

```
 <h:form id="printForm">    
...
  <p:commandButton value="Print" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print" id="print">
                        <p:printer target="text_to_print" />
                    </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: could you show me the EditorBean as well. I mean you print the from EditorBean the attribute text. I guess it is just empty because you set it only to EditorView

Comment: Please search for editorBean and replace it by editorView in line <h:outputText id="text_to_print" escape="false" value="#{editorBean.text}" /> and I bet it works

Comment: the file editorBean does not exist. is it possible to solve this without editorBean? I just want to print text from editor, nothing else :)

Comment: but yes, i changed the code to editorView, but there is still blank pdf.

Comment: <h:outputText id="text_to_print" escape="false" value="#{editorView.text}" />

Comment: Jan edit your question once again with your code you are try to use right now. I will try it at my project and check what is wrong. My code works. I edited it and printed it to pdf

Comment: can you please send me full code that you are using? I tried your code but result is still the same.

Comment: Edit my answer. You never update the outputText you want to print. You need some submit. I did it in the preview button. If you do not want an extra button you can print the editor itself. If you want to print the outputpanel so you have to update the panel by yourself.

Comment: thank you :). I want to export (print pdf) and remove "Preview" button. Is it possible to to that with just one button e.g. "Print"?

Comment: If you flag my answer as an answer :D I posted an edit on your comment

Comment: additional if you just want only one button. For example just go. selt  style="visibility:hidden"  to your print button and it is not viewable but the remotecommand is able to click it and to print and update like discribed. Glad to help

Comment: don't forget to click arrow UP on my question :))

Comment: Hi!  Now everything works! I have only Print and Save button and it's ok. Only one more question, when I click Print I get text in PDF, but I also get text from textEditor (under text editor component). Is it possible to remove this text?